# Is $A\cdot B= B^\top A$ in matrix multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to find a property or definition of the dot product in matrix multiplication that could lead to $A\cdot B= B^\top A$ (being $A\cdot B$ the dot product), but I haven't found it in the textbooks I'm reading.

The only definition I've found about the dot product that could be useful say as follows:

> Let $A$ and $B$ two matrices $m \times n$, the dot product of $A$ and $B$ is defined as: $A\cdot B= tr(A^\top B)$

But I'm not sure if other property or theorem is required.

Comment: Usually $A\cdot B=B^\top A$ is only for $n\times1$ real matrices.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path do you know where could I find that theorem? Because both the matrices I'm using are $3 \times 1$ real matrices.

Comment: @racc_p I would assume you could find it as a remark/exercise in any linear algebra book. It's just that $A\cdot B$ is the standard scalar product and $B^\top A$ is what it is.

Comment: But perhaps you might find it in wikipedia as well. The main point is forgetting about the product-of-magnitudes-times-cosine nonsense completely and just accept the good formula.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe No, the dot product isn't always symmetric. Only on real vector spaces.

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães Oops, I don't know why I wrote such nonsense. Thanks for noticing the mistake.